# How can I get price of grouped product?

Tags: grouped-products, open-graph

I need to set Open Graph price grouped product in `<head>` section.

I can get price of simple product in this way:

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="<?php echo $_product->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>">
```

and it works well. But... **how can I get price of grouped product (the price of the product associated with the lowest price)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this way getting the price of the last product associated (the prices of my products associated are the same for each product so I need to check what is the lowest):

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="<?php 

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(Mage::registry('current_product')->getId());
$grouped_product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');
$groupedParentId = $grouped_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
$_associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);

foreach($_associatedProducts as $_associatedProduct) {
    if($ogPrice = $_associatedProduct->getPrice()) {
        $ogPrice = $_associatedProduct->getPrice();
    }
}

$ogPrice = number_format((float)$ogPrice, 2, '.', '');
echo $ogPrice . " Euro";

?>" />
```

Comment: is it possible to give special price for grouped products.